# How to use external projects in an ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net

UPDATE : 
It turned out that the project I was referring to was a console app.  Rebuilding it as a class library was the solution.

I guess this should be an easy one :

I have only just started ASP.NET and for now need it only as a tool for some  quick intranet reporting.  I have an existing project that supplies the data, but I am not able to refer to it from within my web project.

The library is called (for example sake) 'Lib' and I want to test the static method "HelloWorld()" in Utils.  I have included the Lib project in the References.  The compiler knows it's there cause Intellisense is working and the project dependencies indicate that the webproject is depdendant on Lib.

```
<div>
        <% Response.Write(Lib.Utils.HelloWorld()); %>         
</div>
```

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The
>   name 'Lib' does not exist in the
>   current context

Of course I am very newbee, but in the examples and tutorials for beginners, I haven't fount how to refer to external projects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you add a reference to `Lib` in your web project. Then in your page you add the following:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Lib.NameSpace" %>
```

where `Lib.NameSpace` is the actual namespace of your Utils class.

And that should be it.

Comment: +1 for your trouble, however the question indicates a full qualified name was used and the site indeed referenced the appropriate assembly

Answer (score 2):

Either fully qualify type name, or [@Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx) appropriate namespace into a web page.

And make sure your site references appropriate assembly.

Comment: +1 for your trouble, however the question indicates a full qualified name was used and the site indeed referenced the appropriate assembly